# How to force a select to keep always the same selected value

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say we have multiple forms, each form has 40 selects, the ids of each select have the following structure:

`#id_form-X-{field_name}`

Let's say for example, of those 40 selects, we want 3 of them to be unmodifiable for each form when we change the value of the select, so it will always show the same selected value.

The 3 selects we want to change have the following `field_name`: `ps2_0, ps2_1 and ps2_3`.

So I'm looking for a generic solution that works for:

```
id_form-0-ps2_0
id_form-0-ps2_1
id_form-0-ps2_3
id_form-1-ps2_0
id_form-1-ps2_1
id_form-1-ps2_3
id_form-N-ps2_0
id_form-N-ps2_1
id_form-N-ps2_3
...
...
...
```

Dummy example:

```
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option selected value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

If, for example, the user clicks on the select and selects, for example Saab, the select will show again the value selected by default: Volvo.

I cannot use the 'readonly' or 'disabled' properties for the selects.

What I've tried so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var previous = "initial prev value";
    $("select").on('click', function () {
            previous = $(this).val();
        }).change(function() {
            $(this).val() = previous;
    });
});
```

I'm trying to 'force' the changed select to keep the previous value but didn't work.

Comment: So the select menu is basically not to ever change - it should only ever display the default, selected value??

Comment: Yes! And usually you can do that with the `disabled` option, so the select will be 'static' but I can not use `readonly` or `disabled` properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple Solution**

Reset the value of select with initial value on change.

```js
const selectDD = document.getElementById('cars');
const selectedNode = selectDD.value;
selectDD.onchange = (e) => {
  selectDD.value = selectedNode;
}
```

```html
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option selected value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

**Much Generic Solution**
There should be some unique identifier to differentiate between nodes that can be changed and those to be kept unchanged. Here I have added an `unchanged` custom attribute to select. Pick thode nodes with that custom attribute and on change of that select, reset its value to initial value.
**Example**

```js
const selectDD = document.querySelectorAll('[unchanged]');
selectDD.forEach((node) => {
  node.attributes.initialValue = node.value;
  node.onchange = (e) => {
    e.target.value = node.attributes.initialValue;
  }
})
```

```html
You cant change this
<select name="cars" id="cars" unchanged>
  <option selected value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<br/>
You cant change this
<select name="gender" id="gender" unchanged>
  <option selected value="male">Male</option>
  <option value="female">female</option>
</select>
<br/>
You can change this
<select name="age" id="age">
  <option selected value="10">10</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That sounds promising, what if we don't know the exact ID since it's dynamic ?

Comment: @Cheknov ID was just a representation, we will have some criteria to identify the nonchanging select tags right? That can be made use of.

Comment: @Cheknov I have updated my solution, please have a check into that.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It's somewhat uncomfortable when one's answer is copied.

Comment: to whom does one refer?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `querySelectorAll` to generate a nodelist of all the `select` menus you could assign a default attribute( using dataset here for instance) and set the value within an event listener so that this default attribute is always selected

```js
document.querySelectorAll('form select').forEach( sel => {
  sel.dataset.def=sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
  sel.addEventListener('change',function(e){
    this.value=this.dataset.def
  })
})
```

```html
<form>
  <select name='cars'>
    <option selected value='volvo'>Volvo
    <option value='saab'>Saab
    <option value='mercedes'>Mercedes
    <option value='audi'>Audi
  </select>


  <select name='fruit'>
    <option selected value='apple'>Apple
    <option value='banana'>Banana
    <option value='mango'>Mango
    <option value='plum'>Plum
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain an object which specifies the restricted Select items and the indexes they should always defaults to

```js
let allowedIndexes = {
   cars: 0,
   bikes: 1
}

function preventChange(e) {

   if (Object.keys(allowedIndexes).includes(e.currentTarget.id)) {
   
      let fixedIndex = allowedIndexes[e.currentTarget.id];
      e.currentTarget.selectedIndex = fixedIndex;
   
   }
}
```

```html
<select name="cars" id="cars" onChange="preventChange(event)">
  <option selected value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>


<select name="bikes" id="bikes" onChange="preventChange(event)">
  <option value="honda">honda</option>
  <option selected value="kavasaki">kavasaki</option>
  <option value="suzuki">suzuki</option>
  <option value="yamaha">yamaha</option>
</select>
```